# Excel Insert in a cell missing

Tags: microsoft-excel

Per Microsoft to insert a picture in a Cell in Excel :

On the Insert tab click Pictures.

Click Place in Cell.

Select one of the following sources from the Insert Picture From dropdown menu:

Select Insert > Pictures > Place in Cell > This Device for inserting picture from your device.

Select Insert > Pictures > Place in Cell > Stock Images for inserting picture from stock images.

Select Insert > Pictures > Place in Cell > Online Pictures for inserting picture from the web.

The probelm is I do not see "Place in Cell." option.

I'm using Microsoft Office 2019 Professional. Is this available in newer versions?

Reference: [https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/insert-picture-in-cell-in-excel-e9317aee-4294-49a3-875c-9dd95845bab0#:~:text=Insert%20Picture%20in%20Cell%20from%20the%20ribbon&text=Select%20Insert%20%3E%20Pictures%20%3E%20Place%20in,inserting%20picture%20from%20stock%20images](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/insert-picture-in-cell-in-excel-e9317aee-4294-49a3-875c-9dd95845bab0#:%7E:text=Insert%20Picture%20in%20Cell%20from%20the%20ribbon&text=Select%20Insert%20%3E%20Pictures%20%3E%20Place%20in,inserting%20picture%20from%20stock%20images).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article you provided was referring to Office on the Web.  I tried that with my work account, and there is no option to "Insert in cell".

I think the closest you're going to get is at the link below, which will resize your image to match the cell it is placed above.

https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/insert-picture-excel-cell/

> How to insert picture in Excel cell Normally, an image inserted in
> Excel lies on a separate layer and "floats" on the sheet independently
> from the cells. If you want to embed an image into a cell, change the
> picture's properties as shown below:
>
> Resize the inserted picture so that it fits properly within a cell,
> make the cell bigger if needed, or merge a few cells. Right-click the
> picture and select Format Picture… To embed the picture into a cell,
> change its properties. On the Format Picture pane, switch to the Size
> & Properties tab, and select the Move and size with cells option.

Comment: What version of office you are using at work?

Comment: Also why you think attached article refers to Office on  Web . I don't see any indication inside it.

Comment: Office 365 desktop installed. And on the article it said it was for web under the title. But the link isn't working now, so perhaps it's been flagged as incorrect and Microsoft have pulled it.

Comment: Yes Article was pulled out by  Microsoft.  Clearly they removed the false information!

Comment: Anyway , thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

This function seems to only be available in unreleased versions of Excel (as of February 2024, and I'm using in MacOS). If you want to install one of those releases, click on "Check for Updates", then click the "Advanced" button, and select "Current channel (Preview)". You will now have more recent updates available, but note that the software can generally contain more bugs.